# CFMAIL Caching? Has anyone had seen this before in CF7?

Tags: caching, coldfusion, cfmail

I'm using CFMAIL to send out an email. For some reason, when I edit the email msg in the CFMAIL tag, and save the file, CFMAIL isn't sending new emails with the changes...

Is CFMAIL caching itself or the file that holds the CFMAIL tag?

Thxs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked the template caching in the ColdFusion administrator? If its enabled, then you will needed to clear the cache before you updates will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the wrong file :(